How can I make a big queue faster (read, multithreaded)?
I'm currently facing a challenge with the queue system in Drupal 10. I have a queue that's become quite large (could be up to 100-200.000 items a day) and is taking days to process completely, due to external access to API's. I'm looking for a way to optimize this by possibly executing multiple queue items simultaneously.
Here's what I'm dealing with:

The queue often has hundreds of thousands of items, each taking a significant amount of time to process.
Currently, the queue is processed one item at a time, which is inefficient given the volume.

I've read about potential solutions like using multi-threading or running multiple consumers in parallel, but I'm not sure how to implement these in Drupal 10. Has anyone here tackled a similar issue? Any advice or recommendations on plugins, modules, or custom implementations would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your help! Please let me know if you want more info.
Is a Drupal 10 site, with commerce, and all the queue items is product updates from ERP system.

Are you running the queue in a cronjob? If so can you just run it more often?

Multi-threaded? Drupal makes it impossible to run concurrent cronjobs to avoid conflicts so that modules adding cron hooks and queue items don't need to worry about that. But if you know your code can run in parallel you don't need to use the standard cron system, you can bootstrap Drupal from your own PHP code and trigger it from the outside. Drush can help you to bootstrap Drupal, but you can also write a bootstrap routine from scratch.

Run cron jobs more often, process multiple products in one queue item, or maybe try out if migrations could make it faster for you. Really difficult to help from afar.

Queues can be separately executed by numerous job runners with drush queue:run <queue_id>.

Can I just add that you will probably need the -l option as well, in case any of your queue items generate emails with embedded links. This option will ensure that urls have the correct domain and path for the location of your site.
